# How to properly set up a neural network for coloring grayscale images?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to color the bird images from the CIFAR-10 dataset. 
Problem set-up:
`X: (5000,32,32,1)` where each entry is a grayscale version of the bird images
`Y: (5000,4096)` which is a one hot encode array. for example, the first pixel will have `[0,0,1,0]` where 1 implies which color to be used. 
`Y` is simply the collapsed version of all the one-hot encoding per image.

I've followed many articles that implement coloring of gray-scale images, but my loss/accuracy continues to be high/low.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, (5, 5), strides=(1,1), input_shape=(32,32,1),padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Convolution2D(32, (5, 5),activation='relu', padding='same' ))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same' ))
model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(128))

model.add(Dense(4096, activation='softmax'))



# Compile model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain, validation_data=(val_data,Ytest),epochs=5, batch_size=32)
```

I'm expecting the accuracy to be improved as it progresses through the epochs, but it continues to get worse.

Comment: You can refer [here](https://link.medium.com/y3vl2PmTWV).

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to put some work into architecture (which it sounds like you've been thinking about), but to simply black-box it, you can pump in the gray images and draw out the color images. Why not?

Use model.summary() to make sure your shapes are to your liking. (See below)

I haven't tested this code, but it should be pretty close...

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(32,32,1)))

model.add(Conv2D(32,(5,5),strides=(1,1), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(SpatialDropout2D(rate=0.2)) # holla at this layer
model.add(Conv2D(32,(5,5), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPool2D((2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(5,5),activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(Dense(128))

# have to upsample to get your height/width back from max pooling!
model.add(UpSampling2D((2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(3,(2,2),activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))


model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mse')
model.summary()
```

Here's the output of `model.summary()`. The output layer is (32,32,3); 32 height, 32 width, channels. 
[image: model summary][1]

Now just train it with grayscales as X, and the color originals as Y. And post results, for the curious!